# pandas read_excel every kth column

Tags: excel, pandas

I am trying to read every kth column of an Excel file using `pandas.read_excel`.  From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) `usecols` option with a callable seems useful:

> If callable, then evaluate each column name against it and parse the
> column if the callable returns True.

Is there a way for the callable to take in the column number rather than column name?  Something like:

```
pd.read_excel('file.xls', usecols=lambda col_number: not col_number % k)
```

Comment: You might have to hand roll the solution using openpyxl

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way that I know of - read the first lines, figure out the number of columns then create an array with every kth column integer index. (And the callable only receives the column name.)

```
import numpy as np

dfe = pd.read_excel(r'D:\jchfiles\excel\jch\house\Rats.xlsx', nrows=1)

k = 3

print(dfe.shape)
(1, 9)

nb_sel_cols = dfe.shape[1]//k

print(nb_sel_cols)
3

sel_cols = np.arange(nb_sel_cols)*k

print(sel_cols)
[0 3 6]

df_rats = pd.read_excel(r'D:\jchfiles\excel\jch\house\Rats.xlsx', usecols=sel_cols)

df_rats.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 16 entries, 0 to 15
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   Unnamed: 0  3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   Inside      3 non-null      float64       
 2   Where       3 non-null      object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 512.0+ bytes
```